# Trying to understand a method

Tags: java, methods

I have a method which I have to write called personalize. This is what it's suppose to do / what I've done so far.

```
// personalize takes a String and validates it
// if it is a valid plate, it changes the plateNumber to 
// the new plateNumber and calculates the cost of the plate.
// the method returns true if the new plateNumber is valid and the plate was changed,
// and false if the new plateNumber was invalid and no changes were made.
// A personalized plate may be 3 up to 7 chars and 1 space or dash
// Use letters, numbers, dashes, and spaces ONLY
// A personalized plate costs $10 extra plus $5 per letter (not including dashes or spaces)

public boolean personalize(String vanity)
{   
    boolean valid = true;
    vanity = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < vanity.length(); i++)
    {
        if(vanity.length() < 7 && vanity.length() > 3)
        {
            valid = true;
        }
        if(Character.isLowerCase(vanity.charAt(i)) || vanity.length() > 7 || vanity.length() < 3 ||
        vanity.charAt(i) == '!' || vanity.charAt(i) == '.' || vanity.charAt(i) == '$' ||
        vanity.charAt(i) == '#' || vanity.charAt(i) == '*' || vanity.charAt(i) == '_' || 
        vanity.charAt(i) == '@' || vanity.charAt(i) == '^' || vanity.charAt(i) == '&')
        {
            valid = false;
        }            
    }

    if(valid = true)
    {
       plateCost += 25;
    }
    return valid;
}
```

I know everything I have in this method isn't completely correct but I'm extremely confused on it. I was thinking about writing a helper method, but I'm unsure if it would be for the cost (newCost) or for the new plate number (personalizedPlate). Or would I have to write both? I'm not simply looking for the answer to my work. I'm really looking for someone to help me through the problem to better understand what to do and why I have to do it that way.

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow isn't meant for this kind of question.  It's for asking specific questions, not general things like "help me through the problem".  For that, I think you need a discussion group (which we're not), or a tutor.

Comment: this code is wrong `if(valid = true)` as it is doing assignment rather for as test for equality

Comment: Should start with `valid = false`. Should have length check out side the loop and inside loop if `valid = false` then break it.

Comment: I'd say that the line: `vanity = "";` is a bit problematic, no? ...

Comment: @ajb I know that I need a tutor and it's apparent to me that this isn't for a discussion group. I also know that StackOverflow should be used for more specific questions, but I'm trying to get all the help I can, since this assignment is due tonight and I'm already not doing well in this class. thanks for the feedback on how to better ask questions though. It's appreciated.

Comment: @alfasin I put it there because I was going to set the string vanity to the new plate number if it was valid. I wasn't sure if i should do that in a different method or not though. So then if doing it in the personalize method i wouldn't need vanity = ""; ? or just in general?

Comment: @Liam you don't need to "set the string" since you accept it as a method-parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to do everything in one method. The following code demonstrates one way of implementing these requirements:

```
public class Plate {

    int plateCost = 0;

    public boolean personalize(String vanity) {
        boolean valid = validate3to7chars(vanity);
        valid = valid && hasOnlyOneSpaceOrDash(vanity);
        valid = valid && hasValidCharacters(vanity);
        if (valid) {
            String plateWithoutSpacesAndDashes = vanity.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("-", "");
            plateCost = 10 + plateWithoutSpacesAndDashes.length() * 5;
        }
        return valid;
    }

    private boolean hasValidCharacters(String vanity) {
        String toVerify = vanity.replaceAll(" ", "").replaceAll("-", ""); //remove dashes and spaces
        return toVerify.matches("[0-9a-zA-Z]+"); // verify that the place has only numbers and letters
    }

    private boolean hasOnlyOneSpaceOrDash(String vanity) {
        boolean spaces = vanity.lastIndexOf(" ") == vanity.indexOf(" ");
        boolean dashes = vanity.lastIndexOf("-") == vanity.indexOf("-");
        return spaces && dashes;
    }

    private boolean validate3to7chars(String vanity) {
        return vanity.length() >= 3 && vanity.length() <= 7;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plate p = new Plate();
        System.out.println(p.personalize("abc-52s")); // true
        System.out.println(p.personalize("123 52s")); // true
        System.out.println(p.personalize(" abc62s")); // true
        System.out.println(p.personalize("abc56s ")); // true
        System.out.println(p.personalize("abc562+")); // false
        System.out.println(p.personalize("12345678")); // false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Although i didn't get all my code to work properly, this still helped me a lot. I'm definitely going to look more into some of this code but it helped me a lot. the help was very much appreciated.